# How to convert int“TimeOfDay(00:00)” instring TimeOfDay

Tags: flutter, dart

i am puting a timeOfDay into a text field with controller so i can use it and post to API server , but i have aproblem which is but the tine in string (text)

```
_clockdat1.text = TimeOfDay.minutesPerHour ;
```

and want to do casting into string but the time not back correctly!

```
   _clockTabFrom(BuildContext context) async {
    TimeOfDay time = await showTimePicker(
        context: context,
        initialTime: _clockdate1 != null ?  _clockdate1 : TimeOfDay.now(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
          return Theme(
            data: ThemeData(),
            child: child,
          );
        });
    if (time != null) {
     _clockdate1=time;

//here is the problem 
     _clockdat1.text = TimeOfDay.minutesPerHour ;
     _clockdat1.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(
           offset: _clockdat1.text.length,
           affinity: TextAffinity.upstream));
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
_clockTabFrom(BuildContext context) async {
TimeOfDay time = await showTimePicker(
    context: context,
    initialTime: _clockdate1 != null ?  _clockdate1 : TimeOfDay.now(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
      return Theme(
        data: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.dark(
            primary: Colors.deepPurple,
            onPrimary: Colors.white,
            surface: Colors.blueGrey,
            onSurface: Colors.yellow,
          ),
          dialogBackgroundColor: Colors.blue[500],
        ),
        child: child,
      );
    });
if (time != null) {
 _clockdate1=time;

 _clockdat1.text = _clockdate1.format(context) ;
 _clockdat1.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(
       offset: _clockdat1.text.length,
       affinity: TextAffinity.upstream));
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you want cast int to string, please refer below example.

```
_clockdat1.text = TimeOfDay.minutesPerHour.toString();

or

_clockdat1.text = '${TimeOfDay.minutesPerHour}';
```

Comment: not work with me and i solved it thanks for your effort